Print *.cpp files being compiled with g++
I so far used msvc compiler on command line and the behavior is such that every file being compiled is printed to the console showing which file is currently being compiled.
This is however not the case with g++ which prints no files that are being compiled, it only prints command line used but no other output.
Is there a flag that will instruct g++ to print files being compiled?
A sample command line I use in VSCode is:
 *  Executing task: /usr/bin/g++ -c -xc++ '-fPIC' '-std=c++23' '-Wall' '-Wextra' '-pedantic-errors' '-fdiagnostics-color=always' '-ggdb' '-D BOOST_ALL_DYN_LINK' '-D SHOW_ERRORS' -I${workspaceFolder}/intermediate -I${workspaceFolder}/cpperror/include ${workspaceFolder}/cpperror/source/*.cpp

But this is all I see, how do I make it also print *.cpp files that are compiled?
Since there are many cpp files compiled the console appears as if it's stuck until compilation is done showing nothing except the line above.

Why would you do lik this source/*.cpp? Just provide filenames explicitly.

Because I don't want to update my config every time a new *.cpp file is being added, this way it picks up all *.cpp files automatically and compiles them all.

so just echo *.cpp before compiling?

Understood, but that's a bad practice. When a new file is added, you actually want to update your config, e.g. so that this change is later visible in your commit. Also (at least in case of CMake) once you configure your project using *.cpp, adding new file will have no effect unless you clean/configure again.

It is time for you to graduate to an actual build system. It will happily print filenames being compiled for you while also not recompiling the whole goddamn project every time.

@KamilCuk unfortunately I can't do this in VSCode tasks.json, I can only specify one command which is g++, echo would be second command and this is not possible to add.

"One command" can as well be something around cmake ../ && make -j12.

Then, nowadays, consider cmake. specify one command You can do sh -c 'echo *.cpp && g++ bla bla' which is one command, but I know nothing about vscode.

@Botje I kind of agree with you, do you suggest scripts to be run in tasks.json instead of g++ directly, or perhaps some other build system entirely?

@KamilCuk CMAKE takes a lot of effort to learn, it's sad that g++ seemingly doesn't have a flag to output what it does.

@pptaszni I disagree with the sentiment that I should have to muck about in the build scripts just because I added a file. A new file shows up just as well in commits as an extra line bloating my build script and obfuscating the actual build process because someone insisted on also making it a list of every file in the project.

CMake is a worthwhile investment of all of an afternoon.

@metablaster It takes a lot of effort to master. A basic, starter cmake list file is ~6 lines. And the command(s) are cmake -B build -S . and cmake --build build. I highly recommend not starting with their tutorial, but instead their cheatsheet. I call it a cheatsheet anyway.

VSCode can easily load CMake based projects (with the right extensions). It makes also platform independent development a lot easier.

Thank you, I'll consider playing with Cmake, VSCode extensions for Cmake exist too which is good enough.

Pretty sure msvc doesn't print the file names either, it'll be msbuild doing that. With gcc you're in the same situation, your build system will have an option to print compiler commands
